# Android Studio emulator getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio and its emulator. But it seems that the getExternalStorageDirectory() method doesn't work on the emulator. I have already looked whether "sdCard" is turned on "=yes" in the config.ini - it is. What's the problem? Would be great if someone could help me!

Comment: Try to get status of SDcard before use it by Environment Class: Environment.getExternalStorageState()== Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED ==> It is right, you can use sdcard.

Comment: @sonnv1368 Thanks for the answer! no isn't mounted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getSDPath(){ 
       File sdDir = null; 
       boolean sdCardExist = Environment.getExternalStorageState()   
                           .equals(Android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED); 
       if   (sdCardExist)   
       {                               
         sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      }   
       return sdDir.toString(); 

}

String fileName = getSDPath() +"/" + name;
```